# Line Number is not included in Exception Stacktrace (Code Dynamically Compiled with Roslyn)

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I use the roslyn compiler to compile code on demand.

Now when there is an Exception in the compiled code (example: Divided by Zero Exception) I get in Visual Studio the line number displayed:

[image: StackTrace]

But when I do stacktrace.ToString() the line information is not included.
In frame.GetLineNumber the line number is also 0.

The code for handling the exception:

```
    try
     {
        int i = 0;
        int iiii = 5 / i; 
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
        var frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);

        Console.WriteLine("Exception message: {0}", ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in file: {0}", frame.GetFileName());
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in method: {0}", frame.GetMethod());
        Console.WriteLine("Exception at line numer: {0}", frame.GetFileLineNumber());
     }
```

The Code for Compiling my Code on demand

```
 CSharpParseOptions po = new CSharpParseOptions(LanguageVersion.CSharp7, DocumentationMode.Parse, SourceCodeKind.Regular);
     SyntaxTree parsedSyntaxTree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(code, po);

     List<string> defaultNamespaces = GetUsings(parsedSyntaxTree);

     //// Referenzen über Kommentare heraussuchen:
     List<MetadataReference> defaultReferences = GetReferences(parsedSyntaxTree, rootPfad);

     var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

     var assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
     var symbolsName = Path.ChangeExtension(assemblyName, "pdb");
     var sourceCodePath = "generated.cs";

     var buffer = encoding.GetBytes(code);
     var sourceText = SourceText.From(buffer, buffer.Length, encoding, canBeEmbedded: true);

     var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
         sourceText,
         new CSharpParseOptions(),
         path: sourceCodePath);

     var syntaxRootNode = syntaxTree.GetRoot() as CSharpSyntaxNode;
     var encoded = CSharpSyntaxTree.Create(syntaxRootNode, null, sourceCodePath, encoding);


     CSharpCompilationOptions defaultCompilationOptions =
           new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
                   .WithOverflowChecks(true).WithOptimizationLevel(OptimizationLevel.Debug).WithPlatform(Platform.AnyCpu)
                   .WithUsings(defaultNamespaces);

     CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
         assemblyName,
         syntaxTrees: new[] { encoded },
         references: defaultReferences,

         options: defaultCompilationOptions
     );

     using (var assemblyStream = new MemoryStream())
     using (var symbolsStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
        var emitOptions = new EmitOptions(
                debugInformationFormat: DebugInformationFormat.PortablePdb,
                pdbFilePath: symbolsName);

        var embeddedTexts = new List<EmbeddedText> { EmbeddedText.FromSource(sourceCodePath, sourceText) };

        EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(
            peStream: assemblyStream,
            pdbStream: symbolsStream,
            embeddedTexts: embeddedTexts,
            options: emitOptions);


        if (result.Success)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Kompilierung erfolgreich!");
           try
           {
              var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyStream.ToArray(), symbolsStream.ToArray());
              var parsedCodeInfo = new IM3ParsedCodeInfo() { Assembly = assembly, Erfolgreich = true };

              return parsedCodeInfo;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              Console.WriteLine("Ausnahme aufgetreten:");
              Console.WriteLine(ex);

              var parsedCodeInfo = new IM3ParsedCodeInfo() { ErrorException = ex, Erfolgreich = false };
              return parsedCodeInfo;
           }
        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Kompilierung nicht erfolgreich!");
           foreach (var diagnostic in result.Diagnostics)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.ToString());
           }

           var parsedCodeInfo = new IM3ParsedCodeInfo() { ErrorDiagnostics = result.Diagnostics, Erfolgreich = false };
           return parsedCodeInfo;
        }
     }
```

Picture for provided Solution Suggestion:
[image: Line Numbers not available]

Comment: Does `ex.ToString()` print the line numbers?

Comment: I can't help you for now, but I'm curious: what is the benefit of instantiating a new StackTrace with `new StackTrace(ex, true)` rather than getting it from `ex.StackTrace` in exception handling ?

Comment: @GuillaumeSasdy: ex.StackTrace is a string Property. By creating a StackTrace instance I can use stackTrace.GetFrame(0) and by this get information about the Method for example. But here I used it just to try if this helps to get more information.

Comment: @riQQ : ex.ToString() also doesn't display the line number information.

Comment: You need PDBs to get the line number.

Comment: @PauloMorgado: PDBs are available and loaded for the Code.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe?view=netframework-4.8) `StackTrace.GetFrame(0)` returns the most recent function call, which would be `IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext()` and as @PauloMorgado says, you need the PDB for that function but you **don't** have it. You should iterate over the `StackFrame`s from `0` to `StackTrace.FrameCount - 1`, stopping at the first `StackFrame.GetLineNumber() > 0`

Comment: Does it make a difference if you start the application from a debugger vs starting it normally?

Comment: You only get line numbers when the CLR can find the .pdb file *and* it is capable of understanding the format of the file.  So first make sure that the .pdb file is in the same directory as the .dll file.  PortablePdb requires CoreCLR, the version that's used in .NETCore.  .NETFramework requires Pdb

Comment: @HansPassant: That was my mistake - I used PortablePdb - Please add this as answer to the question. This finally solved the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As per **Hans Passant** comment:

> If you are running in **.NET Core** you'll need **PortablePDB** files; for **.NET Framework** you'll need **PDB** files

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe?view=netframework-4.8) `StackTrace.GetFrame(0)` returns the most recent function call, which would be `IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext()` and you need the PDB file for .NET Framework or PortablePDB for .NET Core for that function (but you don't have it).

You should iterate over the `StackFrames` from `0` to `StackTrace.FrameCount - 1`, stopping at the first `StackFrame.GetFileLineNumber() > 0`:

```
var stack = new StackFrame(ex, true);
StackFrame frame = null;
for (int i = 0; i < stack.FrameCount; i++)
{
    frame = stack.GetFrame(i);
    if (frame.GetFileLineNumber() > 0) break;
}

Console.WriteLine("Exception message: {0}", ex.Message);
Console.WriteLine("Exception in file: {0}", frame.GetFileName());
Console.WriteLine("Exception in method: {0}", frame.GetMethod());
Console.WriteLine("Exception at line number: {0}", frame.GetFileLineNumber());
```

This correctly prints

> Exception message: Sequence contains no elements
>
> Exception in file: [FilePath]\Root.cs
>
> Exception in method: System.Object GetModuleDescription(System.Object[])
>
> Exception at line number: 70

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this. Currently this doesn't help because the Line Number is an all frames 0. How do I make sure the PDB is loaded in this context. In creating the Assembly I add the Information about the PTB - See code in Question: 
var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyStream.ToArray(), symbolsStream.ToArray()); I added an picture for this in the question.

How else would I make sure the PDB is correctly loaded in this scenario. What do I need to add to my code? Why is Visual Studio able to provide the information when the PDB is not loaded?

Comment: Solution found. See original question.

Comment: That's not accurate, .NETCore works with the old format as well.  Easy to see in VS with a sample .NETCore project, Project > Properties > Build tab > Advanced button > "Debugging information" = Full.  I didn't see any announcement about them dropping legacy support in the future, presumably that will happen some day.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to provide the source file in the script options as well.

In my case it looks like this:

```
var options = ScriptOptions.Default
                           .WithReferences(references)
                           .WithFilePath(sourceFile)
                           .WithFileEncoding(sourceFileEncoding)
                           .WithEmitDebugInformation(true)
                           .WithImports(imports);
```

Notice the **WithFilePath(sourceFile)**

In my case i will use to create the script:

```
CSharpScript.Create(this.Content, options, globalType);
```

And that to get the assembly:

```
script.Compile();
var stream = new MemoryStream();
using (stream)
{
  var emitResult = script.GetCompilation().Emit(stream);

  if (emitResult.Success)
    return Assembly.Load(stream.ToArray());
}
```

I just checked, it shows line numbers in the stack trace. Just reply if you need more infos.

[image]

Comment: I do not use CSharpScripts. How would I do this with CSharpCompilationOptions as provided in my example?

Comment: You are right. But internally this is compiling it as well, So it is checkable where the differences are. I will have a look.

Comment: Solution found. See original question comments.